# Возможно ли захватывать нефиксированное количество групп в регулярках?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как пример, я захотел попробовать захватить в группы все аргументы в объявлении питоновских анонимных функций, как пример:
`lambda x, y, arg: a + y + arg`

Мне удаётся получить совпадение всей строки от lambda до двоеточия (это несложно), но вместе с этим, я хочу чтобы каждый аргумент оказался в своей собственной группе.

Далее псевдокод:
match.match = lambda x, y, arg
match.groups = ['x', 'y', 'arg']

Как вариант, я попробовал `lambda ([a-z])(?:,\s([a-z]+))*`, однако подобная регулярка захватывает лишь первый и последний аргумент, хоть я хотел бы (если возможно конечно) захватить каждый аргумент в свою собственную группу

Comment: Оффтоп. Не уверен, что получится, а если и получится, то регулярка наверняка такая страшная, что проще сделать проще регулярку, добавив обработку кодом: 1) вытащить все аргументы 2) сделать разделение по запятой :)